# Weird multiprocessing block importing Numba function

Tags: python, numba

## Environment

- GNU/Linux (Fedora 25).
- Conda environment.
- Python 3.6.1.
- Numba 0.33.0 (np112py36_0).

## Initial setup (works fine)

Two files `main.py` and `numbamodule.py`:

### `main.py`

Which spawns 2 processes to run the `execute_numba` function.

```
import time
from importlib import import_module
from multiprocessing import Process


def execute_numba(name):
    # Import the function
    importfunction = 'numbamodule.numba_function'
    module = import_module(importfunction.split('.')[0])
    function = getattr(module, importfunction.split('.')[-1])
    while True:
        print(str(name) + ' - executing Numba function...')
        # Execute the function
        function(10)
        time.sleep(0.1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    processes = [Process(target=execute_numba, args=(i,)) for i in range(2)]
    [p.start() for p in processes]
    time.sleep(1)
    [p.terminate() for p in processes]
```

### `numbamodule.py`

Which defines a simple function `numba_function`:

```
import numba


@numba.jit()
def numba_function(x):
    total = 0
    for i in range(x):
        total += i
    return total
```

I can run the `main.py` script and see both processes printing:

```
$ python main.py
0 - executing Numba function...
1 - executing Numba function...
0 - executing Numba function...
1 - executing Numba function...
0 - executing Numba function...
1 - executing Numba function...
[...]
```

## Breaking it

The way I break it is a bit weird, but this is what I stumbled upon when trying to minimize a reproducible test case. Please, tell me if you can reproduce the same behavior too.

In `main.py` I just add one of the proposed (bellow) imports after the last `Process` import (i.e.: uncomment one line and try):

```
import time
from importlib import import_module
from multiprocessing import Process

#
# Adding one of the import lines bellow results in a block...
# (you may need to install the packages first in the virtual environment)
#
#import matplotlib
#import Pyro4
#import scipy
#import dill


def execute_numba(name):
# [...]
```

Then one process may block at `execute_numba` function (in particular at the `import_module()` call):

```
$ python main.py 
1 - executing Numba function...
1 - executing Numba function...
1 - executing Numba function...
1 - executing Numba function...
1 - executing Numba function...
1 - executing Numba function...
[...]
```

For me, `matplotlib` and `Pyro4` imports "work" the best. I cannot even get the block a 100% of the runs... :-/

Note that I am simply adding a single import line, not actually using the package. Some other external imports result in a block as well, but I have found that the ones proposed above "work" best (block the most).

## What is happening?

First of all, can you reproduce the same behavior? (specially interested in non-virtualized GNU/Linux machines)

I don't know how to debug this or why could this be happening. Any ideas?

The fact that adding one random `import xxx` triggers the block scares me and makes little sense to me. Could this be dependent on timing/delays and that is why some imports break it and some others do not?

## Notes

- As you can see there is no traceback, the process just blocks.
- If I remove the `import numba` and `@numba.jit` from `numbamodule.py`, then it will always work, so maybe it has something to do with Numba?
- I can reproduce the same behavior also with older Numba/Python versions. Tried with Numba 0.25.0 and 0.22.1 (both with Python 3.5.3).

## Updates

- 2017-07-03: Just to make it clear, I am not looking for a workaround (I already have one in the real code). I am genuinely interested in knowing how to proceed in a case like this. Understand what is going on and learn how to debug and find the problem in order to report it if it is a broken package/build/environment. How would you proceed?
- 2017-07-10: The block occurs in particular at the `import_module()` call.
- 2017-07-11: [Numba issue acknowledged](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2431).

Comment: I can't reproduce the error on Windows 10 Python 3.5 Anaconda installation.  However, I also can't run your code if I don't put `import numba` in `main.py.`  Could you perhaps retry running your code making this small change to see if your errors also go away?  Doesn't matter what I import afterwards, it always works.

Comment: @Matt What do you mean when you say "you can't"? Are you able to reproduce the same behavior, or are you actually getting an exception? (i.e.: you see a traceback printed on `stderr`)

Comment: It works every time I can't reproduce the failure

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the feedback. :-)

Comment: maybe try to run it with "python -m trace" to get some additional info?

Comment: @Peque, so it seems that it was a bug in numba, and that it is now corrected. Maybe you could add an answer from the information you got from the Github issue tracker?

Comment: @jcgiret Yeah, you are right... Added an answer here. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it was a Numba bug, acknowledged in [issue 2431](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2431).

It seems to be fixed now. If you bump into this, update your `numba` and `llvmlite` installations. If that does not fix the problem, you probably should add a comment in that issue to reopen it.

As @stuartarchibald commented:

> [...] it looks like one processed is blocked is because it has in actual fact segfaulted [...]
>
> [...] Segfaults appearing from this location are almost always due to threads performing concurrent operations inside LLVM, or some issue to do with installing functions during Numba's initialisation sequence. [...]
>
> [...] cannot reproduce any more with `llvmlite==0.22.0dev0` and `numba==0.37.0.dev` [...]

Answer (score 0):

This only applies to matplotlib debugging and is really guessing but might help you a bit to narrow down the problem.

You can start your program, when including matplotlib, with:

```
python main.py --verbose-helpful
```

which shows you debug output on the matplotlib initialization. Since it sounded like an issue that is only present on your particular system, there might be some configuartion issue with matplotlibrc configured in such a way that it starts in interactive mode.

Here is an overview on the available debug modes:
https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue is, however, not directly related to Matplotlib. Note that `matplotlib` is only one of the external imports that "break" the code, but there are others as well. Also, adding the `--verbose-helpful` tells me Matplotlib is not starting in interactive mode.

Comment: I am sorry. I had a typo in the flag. Please try the updated version. I did understand that you get problems with other imports as well. I never used **Pyro4**.  After a short scan of the docs, matplotlib as well as Pyro4 seem to use threads which might create problems. However, in matplotlib you can easily deactivate interactive mode and get additional information by adding the proposed flag. I cannot promise  that this leads to the solution but it might be a first step.

Comment: okay, all tries at several system on my site, worked without any locks. Did you try an **strace** to see the last system call python is doing?

Comment: Last lines [look like this](https://pastebin.com/cuF3wW16). Although I am not able to interpret what they mean. 

Comment: Did you terminate the programm with crtl-c ? Since it seems to exit at the end. I understood your first report such that the program hangs and never exits nor produces any output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148761/discussion-between-devnull-and-peque).

Answer (score -1):

Here's reproduction on official Python Docker environment. `Dockerfile` follows (put along your `.py` files).

```
FROM python:3.5

RUN pip install numba matplotlib pyro4

ADD . /opt
WORKDIR /opt

CMD python main.py
```

Then:

```
docker build -t so-44764520 .
docker run --rm -it so-44764520
```

Both work the same way, without the "working" imports, `matplotlib` and `Pyro4`, and with them in `main.py`.

Comment: Thanks. This could be useful for others to try to reproduce the error in case they do not want to work with Conda/virtualenv. It still leaves, however, a lot of questions open. ^^ I myself am unable to reproduce it using Docker, but the main problem is still there: what happens when the block occurs and how to solve it? Without knowing the answer to that question we cannot say Docker solves the problem. Maybe it is just by chance, as the case is very sensitive to little changes (i.e.: simply adding an import line in the code breaks it).

Comment: Yes, the point of the answer is to demonstrate that it's working in official environment, and it doesn't look as it's worth to seek a Python error in your code. Also it indicates that likely your environment, or certain version of conda distribution, is somehow broken. Reinstallation or another version may help. Otherwise you can just go with Docker or another environment as there's no evidence it doesn't solve the problem (or serves as a workaround).

Comment: Yeah, already tried to reinstall and changed Python/Numba versions with no luck (as stated in the question notes). Throwing away the current environment and go with Docker is, at this point, not a possibility. So the question still needs an answer: what to do in a case like this? how to debug and find the problem? (i.e.: if there is something broken: what is it? so that I can report it or fix it)

Comment: Basically, if I want to make sure Docker (or anything else) fixes the problem, I need to know what the problem is first. If there is something broken, I would rather find it and report it now that I have an environment that reproduces it. ;-)

Comment: I agree that it's a good idea to try to reproduce errors and report them to maintainers. The fact that you were not looking for a workaround wasn't clear in the first place. However basing image on [continuumio/anaconda3](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda3/) also works. So it seems the distribution is also okay. Have you tried on another machine?

Comment: Also to the question of how to debug this. It's a little trickier than in single-process case, but the same rules apply. Add logging, and see what code line can your sub-process reach. Add breakpoints and try to debug a sub-process with `pdb` or `PyDev` debugger. [Relevant tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+multiprocessing+debugging) have some details.